# nand2Tetris use of chips as blocks

Tags: hdl, nand2tetris

The nand2Tetris hardware emulator uses .hdl files to load chips.However if we have made a chip(a OR gate) , can we use it as a block for another project?There are built-in functions to write the code of a chip but what if we want to use the chip as a object?Can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know (but feel free to test it). Each of the chips you design has a built-in version that gets used by the hardware emulator if you include the chip -- that way, if you use one of the standard chips you built along the way, you'll always get a known-good chip implementation.